# Simplifying equation with Trace operator

Tags: matrices, trace

I have been looking for a way to simplify the following equation:

$$\frac{ \textbf{A} \textbf{A}^H }{\operatorname{Tr} \left(  \textbf{A} \textbf{A}^H \right)^* \operatorname{Tr} \left(  \textbf{A} \textbf{A}^H \right)}$$

where $\textbf{A}$ is a $M \times P$ matrix. The elements of $\textbf{A}$ are complex numbers.

As the Trace of $\textbf{A} \textbf{A}^H$ results in positive real values (>= 0) we could rewrite the previous equation as:

$$\frac{ \textbf{A} \textbf{A}^H }{ \operatorname{Tr} \left(  \textbf{A} \textbf{A}^H \right)^2}$$

I'd like to know if there is a way to simplify that equation.

Comment: $\left \| A \right \|$ should probably be a scalar. What do you mean by $Tr(\left \| A \right \|^2)$.

Comment: In this case $\lVert \textbf{A} \rVert $ is not scalar, and $ \lVert \textbf{A} \rVert^{2} $ is a square matrix.

Comment: Can you please write your definition of $\left \| A \right \|$.

Comment: $\operatorname{Tr} \left(  \lVert \textbf{A}\rVert^{2} \right)$ will be the sum of all the components in the main diagonal.

Comment: I've just added the definition of $ \lVert \textbf{A} \rVert^2$

Comment: ...Why such weird notation for $A A^H$? Also, why do you have $H$ on the outside of the trace rather than just an ordinary conjugate?

Comment: I've been using this notation for quite some time and nobody never complained. Is it wrong? I have also changed $H$ for an ordinary conjugate as the trace operation results in a scalar.

Comment: Generally $\| X \|$ is expected to be a nonnegative scalar, unless $X$ is something quite exotic like a tensor of order higher than 2.

Comment: I've just fixed the notation accordingly. I hope this allows someone to give a hint on that.

Comment: For any complex number $z$, $z^*z = \lvert z \rvert^2$, so that at least makes the denominator a bit shorter.